# Is "戀"/"恋" a word by itself?

Tags: meaning, characters, meaning-in-context, word

As titled. I saw this lyrics with the sentence,

> 為什麼全世界的戀我都失一遍？

Based on the structure, it looks like the word itself is a noun.
If it is, what does it mean?
I only know the word `戀愛/恋爱`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is not a standard way. Apparently, it is a complain.

失~lose, 戀~love。失戀~fall out of love. The word itself has a vt+noun structure.

Try to understand it from the basic form:

為什麼我失戀了？Why I fell out of love?

One can definitely add adj to a noun(戀). (just for explanation.)

為什麼我失(全世界的)戀？

Now add adv to vt(失). (just for explanation.)

為什麼我(都失一遍)全世界的戀？

Then change order:

為什麼全世界的戀我都失一遍？ Why I fell out of each love all over the world? The singer wants to deliver a strong discourage for being a loser in love in this song.

Answer (score 2):

yes.  but this case it's an inversion of 失戀